# write this mysql query in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, mariadb

I need help on writing this MySQL query in CodeIgniter

```
SELECT *, ABS( post_code - 2015 ) AS distance FROM list_data WHERE business_name LIKE '%cash%' ESCAPE '!' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 6
```

**2015** and **'%cash%'** is coming from input fields

so far I have written it like this but not working

```
public function searchListing($data, $location) {
        $this->db->select('(SELECT *, ABS(`post_code`-' $location' AS distance FROM `list_data` ORDER BY distance)', FALSE);
        $this->db->like('business_names', $data);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Below image is what the table looks like

[image: Showing All Data]

Below image is the query that I want to write in codeigniter

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Just curoius... how is `ABS( post_code - 2015 )` a useful thing?

Comment: Provide the generated SQL and I think the problem will be obvious.

Comment: @Strawberry it uses to get the nearest value of the postcode that I stored in the database

Comment: generated SQL: you can get that using: `$this->db->last_query()`

Comment: @Vickel what do you mean by that? I don't need the value of the last query

Comment: So 'distance' isn't geographical?

Comment: just a debug method to check, how your generated query looks like compared with the expected one

Comment: @Strawberry no, it's just the nearest postcode

Comment: "Nearest postcode" does not work in 2 dimensions.

Comment: hi, @RickJames I've answered this problem, please have a look below.

Comment: @Ace - This is a graphic rendition of postcodes, the ABS() is effectively how many steps along a line:  https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D777or5W4AU6HgS.jpg:large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for the question

```
public function searchListing($data, $location) {
    $q = $this->db->select('*, ABS( post_code - '.$location.') AS distance')
         ->from('list_data')
         ->like('business_name', $data)
         ->order_by('distance')
         ->limit(6)
         ->get()
         ->result();
    return $q;
```

Thank you to @Chivinsdev from CodeIgniter forum for the solution